# modx подключение стилей для контейнера

Tags: modx

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой, что в modx при создании документа-контейнера(псевдоним katalog), во все пути к нему добавляется его псевдоним, из-за чего, если стили у меня лежали в корень_сайта/pub/css/default.css, то теперь он ищите корень_сайта/katalog/pub/css/default.css  Подскажите, что нужно подредактировать, чтобы решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Надо всего лишь было добавить в `<base href="[[++site_url]]"/>` в head)